# Histogram of a Pandas Series with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

What is the simplest way of creating a histogram of a Pandas Series with categorical data?

If the series is numerical, I can easily create a histogram, like:

```
ser_n = pd.Series([2,2,1,4,3,4,4,1,2])
plt.hist(ser_n)
plt.show()
```

However, with categorical values e.g.:

```
ser = pd.Series(['c','c','b','a','b','c','b','a','a','b','c','c'])
```

I haven't found the simple way of producing the histogram.

I have also tried with:

```
ser_c = ser.value_counts()

In [6]: ser_c
Out[6]:
c    5
b    4
a    3
dtype: int64
```

and various way to plot ser_c, but couldn't make it work correctly.
I couldn't find an answer to this case.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ser.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', width=1)` ?

Comment: Thanks, that works. I had actually tried that already and the plot was not showing up. I then realized I was missing the `plt.show()` ; still learning the basics ...